# How can I get DataGrid columns to show mouse hover and sort direction when CanUserSortColumns="False"?

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-4.0, datagrid

I would like to provide my own implementation of sorting behaviour for the WPF `DataGrid` as I am using a paged data model. My paging behaviour is working nicely, however the default sort behaviour for `CanUserSortColumns="True"` causes the current page to sort, however I want to capture this and sort it myself.

I figured I'd be able to provide sorting behaviour by listening to click events on the column headers and sorting appropriately, which works, however when `CanUserSortColumns="False"` the column headers do not respond to mouse interaction any more and do not show the sort direction indicator.

I figured this would be the case, but I wish to know how I can restore the style without having to write a whole template that looks like the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I can't remember whether or not it is possible to get the particular style which does the effects for the buttons or any control.  They are default styles/templates for these controls and are probably not available.  I do remember that templates are available only after shown unless explicitly set.

But, if your whole goal is to implement custom sorting, couldn't you just handle the [`Sorting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.sorting.aspx) event instead?  You even get a reference to the [`Column`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumneventargs.column.aspx) that initiated the sorting and get the [`SortDirection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.sortdirection.aspx) value prior to the sorting (`null` -> `Ascending` -> `Descending` ->).  You could then sort your source as needed.

Comment: My goodness me, thank you Jeff, I can't explain why but I couldn't see the "Sorting" event in both VS2010 "Event" on the property browser OR in intellisense within the XAML. I ignorantly didn't check binding the event via code thinking that if I couldn't see it in XAML it didn't exist. I've done this now and this does everything I want it to do. Thank you very much for your help. Strangely enough, since binding the event in code I can now see it in the event browser and XAML.

Answer (score 0):

Can you leave CanUserSortColumns set to true, then handle the PreviewLeftMouseButton down, do your custom stuff, and set the event to handled so that it doesn't ever get into the default sort logic?

Comment: Unfortunately `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` gives you the Grid itself as the source clicked object, though with a bit of work this could be possible.